# match strings in tuples - python

Tags: python, list, tuples, concatenation

I have to lists of tuples of the form (string, counter), like

```
tuples1 = [('A', 4), ('D', 8), ('L', 38)]
tuples2 = [('A', 24), ('B', 84), ('C', 321), ('D', 19) ...]
```

So the first list is a subset of the strings the second list has, but has a  different number - the count of the string - for each string in the list. So I want all the strings that are in list 1, with **both** numbers.

I want to make it into one list of three terms, of the form ('string', tuples1[1], tuples2[1]). So for eg, with string 'D', it would be ('D', 8, 19).

I'm imagining I need to do something like for each string in tuples1, append an item to a list that has (tuples1[i][0], tuples1[i][1], tuples2[matchStringIndex][1]).
How do I program that?

Comment: you should really use `collections.Counter` to do your counting, or at the very least use a `dict`-based data structure rather than a list of tuples.

Comment: I am using `collections.Counter`, 
     
     
      
 `counted = collections.Counter(lister)          
     sortedCounter = counted.most_common()          
     tuplesIT = sorted(sortedCounter) #tuples form ('word','instances') of all the words in the tweets - "tuples In Tweets"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the list of tuple, which has to be searched, a dictionary and then get the corresponding count from that dictionary, like this

```
tuples1 = [('A', 4), ('D', 8), ('L', 38)]
tuples2 = [('A', 24), ('B', 84), ('C', 321), ('D', 19), ("L", 15)]
dict_tuples2 = dict(tuples2)
print [(char, count, dict_tuples2.get(char, 0)) for char, count in tuples1]
```

**Output**

```
[('A', 4, 24), ('D', 8, 19), ('L', 38, 15)]
```